# Powershell to get list of users who last checked-in files into TFS2010

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs

I'm trying to hack a quick script that runs stylecop to check C# style violations in a project, and then print out the name of the user who last checked it in into Team Foundation Server 2010.

I've gone as far as producing the list of files containing violations:

```
# using Stylecop from http://sourceforge.net/projects/stylecopcli/
StylecopCli\StyleCopCLI.exe -sln mysoluton.sln -set mysettings.StyleCop -out report.xml

[xml]$violations= Get-Content report.xml

$count = $violacoes.StyleCopViolations.Violation.Count

$filenames = $violacoes.StyleCopViolations.Violation | group Source -NoElement | sort Count -descending | % {$_.Name}
```

Any idea on how to do the last part? get the user who last checkedin into TFS? I've been looking at the TFS PowerTools and "tf.exe history" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx) but can't get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

$filenames | %{ tf history $_ /noprompt /recursive /stopafter:1 }